# Wakelock / wifilock different on Ice Cream Sandwich from Gingerbread?

Tags: android

We have an industrial control app that operates in communication with a PC.   The app can run on two devices -  a Samsung Media Player (like a cellphone without the phone) and a Samsung Galaxy 10.1 tablet.

We had a problem with the CPU and WiFi turning off when the display timed out, which was disrupting communication with the PC.   It's OK for the display to go off if the user puts the device down, say, to take a break or go to the bathroom, and it saves battery power, but we want WiFi to still work.   So we added . . .

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakelock;
private WifiManager.WifiLock wifilock;
```

...then, during initialization,

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakelock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "CPUOnly");
wakelock.acquire();
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifilock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "WifiLock");
wifilock.acquire();
```

And in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

This works on the media player.   But the same code on the tablet seems to have no effect - when the display goes out the WiFi also goes out.     The media player is running Android 2.3.5 (Gingerbread), and the tablet is running Android 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich).

Any idea why this would behave differently on these two devices and what we can do to fix it?    Thanks in advance!